Send two SMS with Twiml
I am using a Twilio phone number and I am trying to do this:
Wherever some send a texto to my Twilio number, I want them to receive an automatic reply AND I want their SMS to be forwarded to another phone number.
I found this code for the auto-reply function
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message('Auto reply content');
  callback(null, twiml);
};

And I also found this for the forwarding part:
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(`${event.From}: ${event.Body}`, {
    to: '+13105555555'
  });
  callback(null, twiml);
};

Now I wonder how I can make both of these actions at the same time.
I tried to mix both these codes but I receive the automatic-reply on the wrong phone number

You can use the following example to trigger an auto-replay and forward a message to another number.
Using Twilio API
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const { To, From, Body } = event;

  //   getting twilio client
  /** @type {import('twilio').Twilio} */
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  // sending a reply message to the sender
  await client.messages.create({
    to: From,
    from: To,
    body: 'Auto reply content',
  });

  // forwarding message to specific number
  await client.messages.create({
    to: 'TargetNumber',
    from: 'CompanyNumber',
    body: `${From}: ${Body}`,
  });

  return callback(null, 'OK');
};


Using Twiml
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const { From, Body } = event;

  /** @type {import('twilio').TwimlInterface} */
  const twiml = Twilio.twiml;

  const messageTwiml = new twiml.MessagingResponse();

  // sending a reply message to the sender
  messageTwiml.message('Auto reply content');

  // forwarding message to specific number
  messageTwiml.message(
    {
      to: 'targetPhone',
    },
    `${From}: ${Body}`,
  );

  return callback(null, messageTwiml);
};


I hope that it can help you! :D

I used the TwilML and it worked, Thank you !
